# How to configure nginx for direct access to a path

Tags: nginx

Goodnight. I have a website, let's call it "domain.com", it is already online using nginx and with HTTPS certificate, it is basically a static page built using "npm run build" and it has a button that accesses a content in "domain.com/content" and it works perfectly, but if I refresh the page or try to access it directly by typing the URL, nginx returns the 404 error page. I've already tried to configure a "location = /content {" in my "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" file and it doesn't solve it. From what I find on the internet saying to use declared paths within that location block but my build does not necessarily have the "/content" path but an index.html and a static directory.

Could you give me tips on how I can solve this?